# Insert auto generated multidimensional array to database

Tags: php, mysql, multidimensional-array

I need to create a db function for multidimensional array. How deep the array currently dont know, bcoz they will come from xml file.
I have a sample array

```
Array
(
    [employee] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [lastname] => Kelly
                            [firstname] => Grace
                        )

                    [hiredate] => October 15, 2005
                    [projects] => Array
                        (
                            [project] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product] => Printer
                                            [id] => 111
                                            [price] => $111.00
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product] => Laptop
                                            [id] => 222
                                            [price] => $989.00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [lastname] => Grant
                            [firstname] => Cary
                        )

                    [hiredate] => October 20, 2005
                    [projects] => Array
                        (
                            [project] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product] => Desktop
                                            [id] => 333
                                            [price] => $2995.00
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product] => Scanner
                                            [id] => 444
                                            [price] => $200.00
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [name] => Array
                        (
                            [lastname] => Gable
                            [firstname] => Clark
                        )

                    [hiredate] => October 25, 2005
                    [projects] => Array
                        (
                            [project] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product] => Keyboard
                                            [id] => 555
                                            [price] => $129.00
                                        )

                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [product] => Mouse
                                            [id] => 666
                                            [price] => $25.00
                                        )
                               )
                        )
                  )
        )
)
```

I need to enter these type of array to db and then retrieve them in a good non programmer readable format

I created 2 table... 1st for array key with array level field and another for key=value

I tried this

```
 function array_Dump($array, $d=1){
    if (is_array($array)){
        foreach($array as $key=>$val){
            for ($i=0;$i<$d;$i++){
                $level=$i;
            }
            if (is_array($val)){
               if (is_int($key)){

                array_Dump($val, $d+1);
                }else{
                $query = "insert into xml_array (level, input) VALUES ('$level','$key')";
              insert_sql($query);
                array_Dump($val, $d+1);
               }
            } else {
                $query = "insert into xml_data (array_id,level_id, array_key,array_value) VALUES ('$insert_id','$level','$key','$val')";
                insert_sql($query);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: in db create column with data-type `JSON`, then insert into db result of `json_encode($array)` and when you want to read it in non-programmer readable format convert it back to array `json_decode($row['json_column'])` and print it as you did with original array

Comment: Ok, but not able to display it in a good readable format.... i m trying with table/div... but not succeed

Answer (score 0):

Create a table like this:

**attributes(id, parent_id, properties)**

where `id` will be the `primary key`, `parent_id` will be the `id` of the parent record and `properties` will be a small json field with the atomic properties. This way you support any depth the XML may throw towards your direction.

As about non-programmer representation. For instance you could use a `table` (you can solve that with `div`s as well) which will contain a row for each element in the top level array. Such a row would contain separate columns for each property. When a property is an array, then the given cell will be a table of its own, which will be handled similarly as the first `table`. It is advisable to make the inner `table`s collapsible, so if one wants to see the main levels only, the user will not have to scroll for a long while.

Comment: @PawanKumar what did you try to do and how was it not working?